# Running a powershell .ps1 script without loading any profile

Tags: powershell, external, profile

I am trying to  run powershell script version 5.1 in windows 2012R2

powershell.exe -NoProfile D:\test2.ps1 on the powershell command  console (I do not the script session using any profile on the system)

### Now I am checking in the test.ps1 script what  profile is loaded in test.ps1 script

$profile

---

I get output 
**C:\Users\XXXXX\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1**

Any thought why any profile start up in my session.

Comment: my understanding is that the `$Profile` lists the one that _would_ be loaded, not the one that _is_ loaded. remember that it will list a file _that does not exist_. [*grin*]

Answer (score 2):

The profile isn't loading, because you specified `-NoProfile` on `powershell.exe`. However, the `$profile` variable is still defined.